# Creating a new variable conditional on two vectors of different length using conditional statements

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, string-matching

I have two vectors of unequal lengths. I am trying to populate a variable based on first, whether or not the strings match in the two given vectors, and also trying to take the values from one vector to populate the values of resulting vector.

The data are as follows:

```
a<-data.frame(cbind(c("Ab", "Ng", "Dc"), c(1, 0, 1)))
b<-data.frame(cbind(c("Ab", "Ng", "Rt", "Dc", "Ty"), c(rep(NA, 5))))
```

Where the first vector are a sub-set of the larger vector (b), and these should be matched across vectors. I would like to set up an indicator variable in the larger vector (b). Imagine the following scenario: all strings represent students in a class. The indicator associated with vector a indicates ethnicity, but all the names in vector a are females. The second vector (b) represents all students in the class. End result: "Ab" and "Ng" would then have the value 1, and all other students would have 0.

My script for the loop is currently:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(b)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(a)){
    if(as.character(b[,1][i]) %in% a[,1] & a[,2][j]==1){b[,2][i]==1}
    else{b[,2][i]<-0}
  }
}
```

Which yields the following result:

```
structure(list(X1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("Ab", 
"Dc", "Ng", "Rt", "Ty"), class = "factor"), X2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0)), .Names = c("X1", "X2"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

The desired result should be:

```
structure(list(X1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("Ab", "Dc", "Ng", "Rt", "Ty"), class = "factor"), X2 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0)), .Names = c("X1", "X2"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

My question is: ***Why is the result not matching with the raw input? How can I get this loop to properly execute the process I want so I can get the desired result?***

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: The result should be:

structure(list(X1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("Ab", 
"Dc", "Ng", "Rt", "Ty"), class = "factor"), X2 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 
0)), .Names = c("X1", "X2"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

"Ab", "Ng", "Dc" are all in vector b, only "Ab" and "Ng" have 1 for the indicator. "Dc" is present but its value for the final indicator should be 0 just as "Rt" and "Ty" are zero for the final indicator because they were not present in the smaller vector (a).

Comment: Possibly `x <- as.character(a[,2])[match(b[,1], a[,1])]; ifelse(is.na(x), 0, as.numeric(x))`

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for below? An attempt based on the best of my understanding on the narrative.

```
a<-data.frame(cbind(c("Ab", "Ng", "Dc"), c(1, 0, 1)))
b1<-data.frame(X1 = c("Ab", "Ng", "Rt", "Dc", "Ty"))
library(data.table)
setDT(a); setDT(b1)
setkey(a, X1)
out = a[b1]
out[is.na(out)] = 0
out
   X1 X2
1: Ab  1
2: Ng  0
3: Rt  0
4: Dc  1
5: Ty  0
```

Comment: I am confused by your use of the function setDT(), since this is not included in the package documentation for data.table{}

Comment: @DVHughes, Are you using the latest version? It's there. What it does is to convert dataframe to datatable. You could make a data.table at the start. Then no need to use setDT. Check: ?setDT

Comment: No, I am not using the latest version although I did update and your answer did work on the example code.

When I ran this on my full data set of ~ 12k observations it produced: "Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian) NULL else as.integer(max(nrow(x)", when I set cartesian=T it produced more rows than I had in the original data.

Comment: @DVHughes,Couldn't comment further until we have better understanding on your dataset, as opined by BondedDust.  What you see is a feature of allow.cartesian to handle duplicated key.  It'd be useful for some cases. Please check documentation and SO here.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need a simple left join of `a` in `b`. An alternative using dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- b %>% 
  left_join(a, by="X1") %>% 
  mutate(X2 = ifelse(is.na(X2.y), 0, X2.y %>% as.character %>% as.numeric)) %>% 
  select(X1, X2)
```

Result:

```
> df
  X1 X2
1 Ab  1
2 Ng  0
3 Rt  0
4 Dc  1
5 Ty  0
```

I worked with your example data.frames and I don't know how your real data.frames is set. But be aware of the column types. I had to use `as.character` followed by `as.numeric` to get things right. Seems that `factor´ is not what you need there.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Better to use vectorized function like `%in%` assuming I understood the desired result:

```
> b$X2 <- as.numeric( b$X1 %in% a$X1 )
> b
  X1 X2
1 Ab  1
2 Ng  1
3 Rt  0
4 Dc  1
5 Ty  0
```

In general it is a very bad idea to use the form `data.frame(cbind...))` since you will always coerce the mode of all the columns to a single mode.

Comment: No, you did not understand the final result. I am not simply matching strings, but I am matching strings and then coding a variable based on an indicator that is associated with one set of strings and not the other.

Imagine the following scenario: all strings represent students in a class. The indicator associated with vector a indicates ethnicity, but all the names in vector a are females. The second vector (b) represents all students in the class.

End result: "Ab" and "Ng" would then have the value 1, and all other students would have 0.

Comment: Edit your question body to reflect this. You should include an example that matches your text and finish with the correct result.

Comment: @ DV Hughes: Ab and Dc should have values of 1 (according to your desired structure in question) while in your comment here you mentioned Ab and Ng!

Answer (score 0):

Following may help:

```
> cc = rbind(a[a$X2==1,], b)
> cc[!duplicated(cc$X1),]
  X1   X2
1 Ab    1
3 Dc    1
4 Ng <NA>
5 Rt <NA>
7 Ty <NA>
```